# 3D project shape to 2D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, 2d, projection

In my demo project I'm creating objects in 3D and display an axis coordinate system.

I want to plot 3 different frontal views (frontal view, top view, side view) of the 3D object to the surfaces the axis spread out.

Currently I'm only able to plot the bounding boxes, but I want to plot the contour.

I have drawn it it with the red pen into the bounding box, so you can see what I mean :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to simply render using the same view and projection matrix, but apply a shadow matrix. This is simply a scale of 0 for the plane you wish to render it onto with the translation for that plane to place it in world space where you want.

Eg: To render onto Z = 4.0

```
matrix3d = 1, 0, 0, 0,   
           0, 1, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 4,
           0, 0, 0, 1
```

I think that's the right way around for wpf but you'd probably just use System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D functions to make it.